# Enable Dark Screen on Samsung

Tags: samsung, accessibility

I'd like to try out the dark screen mode on my Galaxy J7 max but the option has been greyed out and I was wondering why. Any clues? This option is found under Accessibility>Vision
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that your device is updated to at least Android 10.
2. Slide down the notification and settings shade.
3. Depending on how you've organized your system settings in the pulldown menu, you may need to swipe over a screen to see the dark mode setting (it has a moon icon).

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on the talk back feature, dark screen will work but if you turn talk back off, dark screen stops working. I think this is because it was only made for the purpose of privacy for people who have bad vision and need talk back.